# JQuery window.resize is constantly prepending my HTML more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I'm trying to make it so my jQuery doesn't prepend my HTML constantly as I resize my window and instead only prepend once.

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        $("header > .content-max > .row").prepend( '<a href="#" class="logout"><svg class="pulse" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22.3 22.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22.3 22.3;" xml:space="preserve"><g><g><path class="st0" d="M11.2,0C5,0,0,5,0,11.2c0,6.2,5,11.2,11.2,11.2c6.2,0,11.2-5,11.2-11.2C22.3,5,17.3,0,11.2,0z M17.6,17.6 c-1.7,1.7-4,2.7-6.5,2.7c-2.4,0-4.7-1-6.5-2.7C3,15.9,2,13.6,2,11.2c0-2.4,1-4.7,2.7-6.5S8.7,2,11.2,2c2.4,0,4.7,1,6.5,2.7 c1.7,1.7,2.7,4,2.7,6.5C20.3,13.6,19.4,15.9,17.6,17.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M11.2,4.3c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1l0,11.8c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1l0-11.8C12.2,4.7,11.7,4.3,11.2,4.3z"/></g></g></svg></a></a>' );
        $("header > .content-max > .row").prepend( '<a href="#" class="mobile-nav"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>' );
        $(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("pushed");
            $("#main-nav").slideToggle(300);
        });
        $("body").prepend('<a href="#" class="top">Top</a>');
    }
});
```

I get a strange effect where the SVG is added constantly as the window is resized. At the moment I've only managed to get this working properly on page load but am trying to make it behave like a media query.

See example result:

[image]

EDIT: I've just noticed that this also breaks the window.load of it. :(

Update: Rough JSFIDDLE here https://jsfiddle.net/t1xyyqfn/

Comment: can you tell me what is the problem ?

Comment: The `resize()` event is fired once for *every single pixel* that the window is resized - hence your problem. What behaviour are you expecting here?

Comment: I just want it to be like a media query. so it fires once under 1024 but I also want it to work on page load not just on resize.

Comment: If I remove the window.resize it works on load but then not on resize...

Comment: You would be better to have the element already in the DOM and then just hide/show it using an actual CSS  media query. The issue here will always be that succesive elements will be created every time the window is resized.

Comment: Ya, use media queries to display/hide element instead

Comment: could you have a variable svgShowing = true when the it is showing and only prepend() when it is not true  and the $window.width() is < 1024?

Comment: I'd be happy with that and keeping it simple too. I just didn't want to add that huge chunk of code there. Ok I guess I'll give that a go instead :)

Comment: Hi jojojohn that sort of makes (to me) but is a little too advanced. I think keeping it more simple seems like a good shout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try remove the `on` event listener and try this...

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
$( "body" ).prepend( "<div>" + $( window ).width() + "</div>" ); //example
});
```

will you please give me a fiddle if this doesn't work!

**or**

you can use a css media query which does the same thing:

```
@media(min-width: 1024px){
  /*css styles*/
}
```

this code will run once the media condition is correct i.e if the browsers window width is greater than or equal to a width of 1024px (or if it gets a min-width of 1024px) .so add the tags in HTML and style it accordingly then set it display to none i.e `display:none` then set it display to `display:inline` or `display: inline-block`
refer to MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) if you want

thanks.

Comment: Added a fiddle in  the question :0

Comment: i think your code doesn't work because the on event listener keeps listening to the event almost everytime after the window is loaded well i'm not sure but your fiddle is working fine

Comment: Yeah I think I've approached this wrong. May have to go back to just hiding and showing with CSS

Comment: but please mark my answer as it will help orthers out... thanks

Comment: The answer is only partially correct though..? Going back to a CSS solution would be a correct answer as it's a solution. If you want to provide that I will mark it as correct :P

Answer (score 0):

You are prepending this every time you resize the window a pixel.

This might help:

```
$resized = false;

$(window).on('resize', function(){

if($(window).width() <= 1024 && $resized==false){

$("header > .content-max > .row").prepend( '<a href="#" class="logout"><svg class="pulse" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 22.3 22.3" style="enable-background:new 0 0 22.3 22.3;" xml:space="preserve"><g><g><path class="st0" d="M11.2,0C5,0,0,5,0,11.2c0,6.2,5,11.2,11.2,11.2c6.2,0,11.2-5,11.2-11.2C22.3,5,17.3,0,11.2,0z M17.6,17.6 c-1.7,1.7-4,2.7-6.5,2.7c-2.4,0-4.7-1-6.5-2.7C3,15.9,2,13.6,2,11.2c0-2.4,1-4.7,2.7-6.5S8.7,2,11.2,2c2.4,0,4.7,1,6.5,2.7 c1.7,1.7,2.7,4,2.7,6.5C20.3,13.6,19.4,15.9,17.6,17.6z"/><path class="st0" d="M11.2,4.3c-0.6,0-1,0.4-1,1l0,11.8c0,0.6,0.4,1,1,1c0.6,0,1-0.4,1-1l0-11.8C12.2,4.7,11.7,4.3,11.2,4.3z"/></g></g></svg></a></a>' );

$("header > .content-max > .row").prepend( '<a href="#" class="mobile-nav"><span class="icon-bar"></span><span class="icon-bar"></span></a>' );

$(".mobile-nav").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("pushed");
    $("#main-nav").slideToggle(300);
});

$("body").prepend('<a href="#" class="top">Top</a>');

$resized = true;

} else {

$resized = false;

}

});
```

Hope this makes sense!

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks I will look at this and learn from it and when I get working I'll mark as correct :)

Comment: DIdn't work for me - still got the constant prepending